# Regex that matches all div tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

### I need a regex expression that matches all div tags in the HTML code whithout using a DOM parser

I've tryed this

```
var expression = /<div\s*"?.*"?\s*>[\S\s]*?<\/div>/gi;
var regexpress = new RegExp(expression)

matches = text.match(regexpress);
if (matches != null) { returnarray.push(matches); }
return returnarray;
```

But the result:

```
input text:
<div wdlm></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>

output array:
element 1:<div wdlm></div> <div></div>
element 2:<div></div>
```

It takes 2 divs at the same time for the 1st element of the array.

---

### By reading comments this is the solution

```
        var returnarray = [];
        var matches = null;
        var expression = /<div\s*"?.*?"?\s*>[\S\s]*?<\/div>/gi;       
        var regexpress = new RegExp(expression);
        
        matches = text.match(regexpress);
        if(matches != null) {
            returnarray.push(matches);
        }
        
        return returnarray;
```

---

Also, I'm flipping my brain over a question:

**Can the regex be allocated dynamically?**

Something like

```
var expression = /<VARIABLE\s*"?.*"?\s*>[\S\s]*?<\/VARIABLE>/gi;
```

Where VARIABLE it's a `var VARIABLE`, taking every element in the code by changing the input of `VARIABLE` and not only `div`?

---

Could someone help me with this, please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](/a/1732454/90527)

Comment: *Do not use regex to parse HTML. Use a HTML parser!*

Comment: @outis "Does this answer your question? RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags" No. I want a regex that works for the `div` tags (not only open tags) and that gives also the content for editing it after.

Comment: @MikeM "if returnarray is an array then it doesn't make sense to use return returnarray || []; as even an empty array is truthy". It was part of a function. Now i edit it so it's more comprensible. Tnx 

Comment: Regarding composed regex, I think you can do something like :  `new RegExp("/" + variable + "restOfRegex" + "/g")`  afterall it's a string inside `RegExp()`

Comment: @MikeM "Just put a ? after the .*" Ok, I've done it. It's esactly what i wanted.

Comment: @Mara Black "Regarding composed regex, I think you can do something like : new RegExp("/" + variable + "restOfRegex" + "/g") afterall it's a string inside RegExp()" You're the queen. It's what I answered. I've to try it. Tnx lady ‍♂️

Comment: @MaraBlack the only one thing it's that these regex for javascript are not between quotes `/<div\s*"?.*?"?\s*>[\S\s]*?<\/div>/gi`. So how to edit it? like `< VARIABLE \s*"?.*?"?\s*>[\S\s]*?<\/ VARIABLE>` ?

Comment: What if the `div` tags are nested? Why don't you want to use a parser to DOM?

Comment: @Peter Thoeny "What if the div tags are nested?" your answer it's the top answer. Donnow. I wait someone that knows more then me. "Why don't you want to use a parser to DOM?" There's no why. I want to do it with the regex so can be readactable to other languages

Comment: @xaaaaaaaaaaaa: You could use regex to parse nested HTML tags, but that requires 3 regex steps: 1. add nesting level to tags, 21. parse start and end tag with matching level, 3. remove nesting level. More at https://twiki.org/cgi-bin/view/Blog/BlogEntry201109x3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't recommend using regex to parse an HTML string. If you can live with the limitation, here is a regex solution for arbitrary HTML tags that does not support nesting, and fails with corner cases, such as `<div title="</div>"></div>`:

```js
const input = '<div wdlm></div>\n' +
  '<div></div>\n' +
  '<div></div>';

function parseTags(tag, str) {
  let re = new RegExp('<' + tag + '\\b\\s*"?.*?"?\\s*>[\\S\\s]*?<\\/' + tag + '>', 'gi');
  return str.match(re) || [];
}

let tags = parseTags('div', input);
console.log('- input: "' + input + '"\n- tags: ' + JSON.stringify(tags, null, ' '));
```

Output:

```
- input: "<div wdlm></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>"
- tags: [
 "<div wdlm></div>",
 "<div></div>",
 "<div></div>"
]
```

Comment: oooooooooooook. But, you parsed dinamically the tags using this `parseTag` function. Beautiful code and beautiful use of `JSON.stringify(tags, null, ' ')`, I forgotten this. For now I don't have tag nested. BUUUUUT if there are nested tags?! Anyway I think you answer it's the top answer for now. Waiting a little time. In none other says better you are on the top. Tnx 

Comment: You can properly parse nested structures with regex using three steps: 1. add nesting level to opening and closing tags, 2. identify matching opening and closing tag based on annotated nesting level, 3. clean up nesting level annotation. More at https://twiki.org/cgi-bin/view/Blog/BlogEntry201109x3

Comment: Would you care to accept this answer? Please add some more details to your question if you need more help.

Comment: Normally I do not accept incomplete answers to questions. I don't need more help. It'a only a incomplete answer that don't considers nested tags. So, for this time for you there's a made exception only because none more has answered @ that. Tnkx all that's the verdict. Accepted and don't think about it anymore  ‍☠️